# Merge One Array Key And Another Array Value PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array As Follow

**Array 1**(*this is default array*)

```
Array
(
    [0] => pname
    [1] => minmrpprice
    [2] => maxmrpprice
    [3] => unittype
    [4] => minorder
    [5] => pdetails
    [6] => status
    [7] => product_group
    [8] => specification
)
```

**Array 2**(*this is dynamic array*)

```
Array
(
    [pname] => Designer Dress By Textilemart
    [h1] => 1
    [userid] => textilemart
    [minmrpprice] => 1212
    [maxmrpprice] => 
    [unittype] => Piece
    [minorder] => 12
    [pdetails] => adsfadf
    [_wysihtml5_mode] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [product_group] => 2
    [addGroupInput] => 
    [categories] => 2
    [0] => 299
    [1] => 84
    [2] => 71
    [3] => 45
    [specification] => 84
    [4] => 
    [submit] => Update Product
)
```

Now all i need is i want to merge array 1 value with array 2 key and

1. Get only elements that have value in Array2
2. remove all other key and values

As Result for above Example is as follow

```
Array
(
    [0] => pname
    [1] => minmrpprice
    //[2] => maxmrpprice(THIS DON'T SHOW BECAUSE VALUE IS EMPTY)
    [3] => unittype
    [4] => minorder
    [5] => pdetails
    [6] => status
    [7] => product_group
    [8] => specification
)
```

I also Tried merge_array but it returns me like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => pname
    [1] => minmrpprice
    [2] => maxmrpprice
    [3] => unittype
    [4] => minorder
    [5] => pdetails
    [6] => status
    [7] => product_group
    [8] => specification
    [pname] => Designer Dress By Textilemart
    [h1] => 1
    [userid] => textilemart
    [minmrpprice] => 1212
    [maxmrpprice] => 
    [unittype] => Piece
    [minorder] => 12
    [pdetails] => adsfadf
    [_wysihtml5_mode] => 1
    [status] => 1
    [product_group] => 2
    [addGroupInput] => 
    [categories] => 2
    [9] => 299
    [10] => 84
    [11] => 71
    [12] => 45
    [specification] => 84
    [13] => 
    [submit] => Update Product
)
```

i do not need like this

Comment: There is nothing wrong. And just wait a moment so you will get a solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

loop through the array1 and use check if value in array2

```
foreach($arr1 as $a){

if(!empty($arr2[$a])){

 $new[] = $a;
  }
}

print_r($new);
```

Comment: what you're getting now ? can you show the expected op

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that does exactly what you want, which is called `array_intersect_key`, which deletes all values from an array that do not occur as a key in another array. [array_intersect_key documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)

The problem you just have is, that your first array does not have the wanted fields as keys, but as values instead. Luckily there is a function to simply swap these, that is called `array_flip`. `array_flip` will turn all values into keys and their keys into values. This only works with `string`/`int` values though. [array_flip documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php)

To make an intersection of your two arrays the following code is the way to go in PHP:

```
$wantedKeys = array_flip($array_one);
$result = array_intersect_key($array_two, $wantedKeys);
```

The result will be the part of `$array_two`, which's keys occur in the `$wantedKeys` array as well.